# Jquery Removeclass rails not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me in this? I want to remove a class on button click, but it works only after 1 click is already done. when i click first time, nothing happens. when i click second time, class is removed
HTML Code

```
<%= form_for :email_form, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, url: search_reduce_credits_by1_path, id: "candidate-email-modal-form", remote: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :lead_id, :value => lead.id %>

    <div class=text-right>
    <%= f.button class: "btn btn-primary", id: "show-mail-btn" do %> 
                                        Show Email
     <% end %>
     </div>

     <% end %> 

    <small class="blurfilter" id="blurred_email_<%= lead.id %>"> <%= lead.email %></small>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#show-mail-btn').click(function (){
        $('#blurred_email_1').removeClass('blurfilter');
    });
});
```

When I update jquery to this,

```
$(document).on('click', '#show-mail-btn', function(){
  alert("Hey");
  $('#blurred_email_1').removeClass('blurfilter');
});
```

"Hey" also appears on second click and appears two times, before class is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to account for turbolinks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
     $('#show-mail-btn').click(function(){
         $('#blurred_email_1').removeClass('blurfilter');
     })
})
```

See this question for more details:

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: It does not even remove class on any number of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#show-mail-btn', function() {
  $('#blurred_email_1').removeClass('blurfilter');
});
```

```css
.blurfilter {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-mail-btn">Show Email</button>
<input type="email" id="blurred_email_1"  value="test@example.com" class="blurfilter" />
```

This creates a delegated event handler which will continue to work even after Turbolinks has switched the document contents.

This is an idempotent transformation since it does not rely on adding event handlers to actual elements.

See:

- [Turbolinks - Making Transformations Idempotent](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent)
- [jQuery.on](https://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: Again just works on second button click. Is it that element is unavailable during first click?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some completely unrelated code thats messing with you, try pressing "Run code snippet" and you will see that it does work as advertised.

Comment: "Is it that element is unavailable during first click? " No, by the time you can click an element the document is ready.

Comment: any other alternative to show hidden email by button click in jquery?

Comment: There are tons of ways to skin a cat but you should really concentrate on figuring out why its not behaving properly on your system as that will most likely haunt you anyways.

Comment: Getting same behavior with attr('class')

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove turbolink gem and include in html.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I just had to remove onclick from js.erb file because it was already being called from form button click. It works perfectly now!